# How do I get the Name of two different ID in 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table with columns:

UID_person, UID_personHead, Firstname, LastName

The value of UID_personhead is equivalent to UID_person. UID_personHead is the UID_person of managers
So I want to query it and return something like

| UID_person | FirstName | LastName | Name of manager using the UID_personHead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sarah | Smith | Jack |
| 2 | Jacob | Smith | David |

I tried this query

```
SELECT UID_Person, FirstName, LastName
(SELECT FirstName
from person WHERE UID_person IN (SELECT UID_PersonHead From person)) AS Name of the manager
```

Comment: Look up `self join`

Answer (score 1):

Just self join the table back to itself on `UID_PersonHead`

```
SELECT p.UID_Person, p.FirstName, p.LastName, m.FirstName
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person m ON m.id = p.UID_PersonHead;
```

Answer (score 1):

your data is like this

```
declare @a table
(UID_person int, UID_personHead int, Firstname varchar(30), LastName varchar(30))
insert into @a 
(UID_person,UID_personHead,Firstname,LastName) values
(1 ,3,'Sarah','Smith'),
(2 ,4,'Jacob','Smith'),
(3 ,3,'Jack','johnson'),
(4 ,4,'David','johnson');
```

your need to join your table with itself

```
select a0.UID_person, a0.Firstname, a0.LastName,a1.Firstname  
from @a a0
join @a a1
on a0.UID_personHead=a1.UID_person
where a1.UID_personHead<>a0.UID_person
```

Comment: removing names both being personHead and person based on question needs.